# how to print xpath parser

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath

I'm having some trouble in parsing lxml in Python 2.7 / Flask 0.12.

I want to print parsed xpath data, but can't find a way to do it.
Here's my code.

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

def parse_html(html_src):
    target_xpath = //div[@class="primary-content"]//div[@class="mini-cart-product clearfix"]'

    detail_html = html.fromstring(html_src)
    page_tree = etree.ElementTree(detail_html)

    target_value_list = page_tree.xpath(target_xpath)
    #want to print 'target_value_list'

    return target_value_list
```

Here's html_src

```
<div class="mini-cart-product clearfix">
    <div class="mini-cart-image">
        <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795419986.html"><img src="https://www.carters.com/dw/image/v2/AAMK_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-carters_master_catalog/default/dw540ec9a5/hi-res/127G525_Default.jpg?sw=470" alt="Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit" title="Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit"></a>
        <div class="mini-cart-brand">
            <div class="carters"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mini-cart-attributes">
        <div class="product-name">
            <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795419986.html">Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="attribute Size">
            <span class="label">Size:</span>
            <span class="value">
        9M
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="verticalLine">|</div>
        <div class="attribute Color">
            <span class="label">Color:</span>
            <span class="value">
        Blue
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="minicartpricedisplay">
            <div class="price">
        <span class="MSRP price-standard">
        <span class="msrp">MSRP*:
        $14.00
        </span>
        </span>
                <span class="price-standard ">$6.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mini-cart-product clearfix">
    <div class="mini-cart-image">
        <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795039832.html"><img src="https://www.carters.com/dw/image/v2/AAMK_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-carters_master_catalog/default/dw182a85c8/hi-res/118H023_Default.jpg?sw=470" alt="Piqué Polo Romper" title="Piqué Polo Romper"></a>
        <div class="mini-cart-brand">
            <div class="carters"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mini-cart-attributes">
        <div class="product-name">
            <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795039832.html">Piqué Polo Romper</a>
        </div>
        <div class="attribute Size">
            <span class="label">Size:</span>
            <span class="value">
        12M
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="verticalLine">|</div>
        <div class="attribute Color">
            <span class="label">Color:</span>
            <span class="value">
        Blue
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="minicartpricedisplay">
            <div class="price">
        <span class="MSRP price-standard">
        <span class="msrp">MSRP*:
        $18.00
        </span>
        </span>
                <span class="price-standard desktopvisible">$7.20</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I try to print 'target_value_list', then it prints a list of some memory addresses.
Please somebody save me.

I want to print what's in traget_value_list. Wanna know whether or not it has all the items in html_src.

Comment: Can you show us the output? What do you call *some memory addresses*?

Comment: [<Element div at 0x7abc718ada12>, <Element div at 0x7abc748bcb50>, <Element div at 0x7abc718abcd8>] This is the output of print(target_value_list)

Comment: That is the list of elements matched by your `XPath`. Your code works correctly. Can you be more specific about *what output you want to get*? Do you want to get just text content of each element? Show `XPath` you used

Comment: Thanks for your help @Andersson, I edited it.

Comment: What do you mean by "parsed XPath data"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list of text values instead of list of webelements, you might try to use `/text()` syntax in `XPath`: use, for example, `//div/text()` or `//div//text()` instead of just `//div` or use `text` property or `text_content()` method as below:

```
target_value_list = [element.text_content() for element in page_tree.xpath(target_xpath)]
return target_value_list
```

Comment: If I print element.text, then it prints '<Element div at 0x7abc718ada12>'. I want to know what's in there

Comment: I'm not sure you implement my code correctly... You cannot get `<Element div at 0x7abc718ada12>` after calling `text` property. I've updated answer with `text_content()` instead of `text`- this should provide with better results